# Sympy relationals as_set within an interval

Tags: python, sympy

As the title, I want to get intervals of `sin(x) < 0` in `[-5, 5]`

```py
from sympy import Symbol, sin

x = Symbol("x")
y = sin(x) < 0
y.as_set()
```

This will give an error because of periodic solutions, is there a way to do something like this?

```py
y.as_set([-5, 5])  # -> (-pi, 0) ∪ (pi, 5]
```

Thank you!

Comment: `solve(sin(x) < 0).as_set()` does return `Interval.open(pi, 2*pi)`, but that doesn't do what you asked for.  Similarly `solveset(sin(x) < 0, x, domain=Reals)` returns the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method to do this, but you can write your own method to test the value of the function between the zeros and determine whether the interval satisfies the condition.

```py
def posin(eq, r):
    assert isinstance(r, Interval)
    free = eq.free_symbols
    assert len(free) == 1  # univariate
    x = free.pop()
    z = solveset(eq, x, r)  # find zeros
    if not z: return
    assert isinstance(z, FiniteSet)
    for i in (r - z).args:
        if i.inf.is_infinite and i.sup.is_infinite:
            xx = 0
        elif i.inf.is_infinite:xx=i.sup - 1
        elif i.sup.is_infinite:xx = i.inf + 1
        else:xx = (i.inf + i.sup)/2
        if eq.subs(x, xx).is_positive:
            yield i

>>> list(posin(sin(x),Interval(-5,5)))
[[−5, −π), (0, π)]
```

You can also use the symmetry and periodicity of the function and the solution within a period to work out the answer,

```py
>>> solve(sin(x)<0).as_set()&Interval(0,5)
(π, 5]
```